# "Пожертвовать своей жизнью" или "пожертвовать свою жизнь" — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

1. И каждый поклялся: *не бежать с поля боя и быть готовым **пожертвовать своей жизнью** во имя Родины.*
2. И каждый поклялся: *не бежать с поля боя и быть готовым **пожертвовать свою  жизнь** во имя Родины.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используется **только** первый вариант. Пожертвовать жизнью, пожертвовать мечтой и т.д.

Однако в шахматах: пожертвовать (что?) пешку, фигуру, ферзя.

Comment: значит "своей" можно убрать из предложения?

Comment: Да, можно убрать.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: И каждый поклялся: не бежать с поля боя и быть готовым **пожертвовать своей жизнью** во имя Родины

**Все ответы в словаре:**

**ЖЕРТВОВАТЬ**, (св. пожертвовать). 1. (что). **Добровольно отдавать, приносить в дар**. Ж. деньги в пользу бедных. 2. кем-чем. Н**е щадить кого-, чего-л., подвергать гибельной опасности ради чего-л.** Ж. жизнью. Ж. собой. // чем, что. **Отказываться от чего-л., пренебрегать чем-л. ради кого-, чего-л. Ж.** собственными интересами ради общего дела. Жертвуя ладью, шахматист рассчитывал на ничейный исход партии.

Answer (score 1):

В *данном сочетании* правилен **первый** вариант (во втором варианте нужно изменить в сторону устойчивого "*отдать жизнь*"). Как непереходный этот глагол используется в значении "добровольно **расстаться с чем-то** важным (со здоровьем, жизнью, имуществом...) ради чего-то более важного", для этого значения характерно *отсутствие адресата* (пожертвовать кому, на что). Если же жертвуют чем-то конкретно-материальным в пользу какого-л. ведомства или на что-то, то глагол используется как *переходный* ("**отдать в дар**", пожертвовать что). Например:

> Он пожертвовал 1000 рублей на содержание храма (храму, на благотворительные
>   нужды, на лечение детей...).

Answer (score 1):

**Пожертвовать своей** -  это гипотетическая готовность отдать что-то своё. *Вы готовы пожертвовать своей жизнью  ради Родины?*

**Пожертвовать свою** - это определённая направленность на жертвование. *Индеец направился к алтарю, чтобы пожертвовать свою жизнь богу Кетцалькоатлю*.

В вашем случае правильно *Готовы пожертвовать* **своей жизнью**.